# Получение пути к папке, в которую по умолчанию сканер сохраняет изображения/pdf через TWAIN

Tags: delphi-7, c++builder, сканирование

Есть сетевой сканер, через который пользователи сканируют различные документы. Сканы сохраняются в локальные папки пользователей, путь к которым они указывают сами в настройках родного приложения.
У меня есть своё приложение, во время работы которого появилась необходимость подменять этот путь на путь, который задаю я.
Смысл работы такой:

1. Пользователь открывает **мое** приложение, нажимает кнопку "Сканирование"
2. Идет к сканеру и начинает сканировать многостраничный документ, который сохраняется в виде одного или нескольких файлов в папке, которую по умолчанию указываю я.

Вопрос: Как, средствами delphi  или С++ Builder получить этот самый путь, в который сканер сохраняет файлы по умолчанию и заменить его на свой?

Для подключения к сканеру использую EZTwain 1.19.

P.S. Сканер может быть абсолютно любым.

Comment: Возможно тут https://www.codeproject.com/articles/296/a-c-wrapper-for-twain есть. У меня на js код через WIA валяется, на с++ переписать его сложнова-то будет.

Comment: Это немного не то. Само сканирование у меня реализовано, мне нужно получить именно путь к папке, в которую сторонний сканер по умолчанию сохраняет файлы.

Comment: А нельзя настроить на сканере один стандартный путь, запретить его менять, и вашей программой его просто мониторить и перекладывать файлы оттуда туда куда вам надо?

Comment: К сожалению, таких сканеров в реальности более 300 штук, естественно разных фирм и моделей. Пользователь сам устанавливает себе драйвера и выбирает устройство по умолчанию. Централизованно спускать настройки тут практически невозможно.